# accessing superview properties

Tags: objective-c, c, view, parent, subview

I've searched for the answer to this question, and the answers I'm finding don't work.

I have a view that is a subclass of UIView to which I've added a property. I would like to access this property from the subviews created by this view. Is that possible?

I've tried referring to self.superview.propertyname but I get an error that propertyname is not found on object of type UIView. Well, right. I realize that since it's a subclass of UIView, it's a UIView, but how can I get it to know about the extra property I added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of  options, two of them are:

**1. Casting:**

```
@implementation SubviewView
- (void)blah
{
  ((CustomView *)self.superview).property = ...`
}
@end
```

**2. Delegates:**

```
@protocol SubviewViewDelegate
- (void)customView:(SubView *)sv modified:(...)value;
@end

@class SubView
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <CustomViewDelegate> delegate;
@end

@implementation SubviewView
- (void)blah
{
  [self.delegate subView modified:...];
}
@end

@implementation CustomView
- (void)subView:(SubView *)sv modified:(...)value
{
  self.property = value;
}
@end
```

Although the second option is more code, I think it is often better suited. Using delegates reduces coupling and works nicely with the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). For more info see this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-SW1).

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll use the first option for now, partly since I came up with essentially the same solution in my sleep last night, and then try your other solution later.

Comment: Actually, for the project I'm working on, I think the simplest solution is to add a property to the subclass and set it by the coding in the view that instantiates the subviews. It's redundant but simple. And the value in question is not something that will change for this project. I'll keep your suggestions in mind for future projects, though.